# I've created a password protected Web Page. It works, yet, an error displays. Warning: Undefined array key "password" in .... on line 74

Tags: php

I'm receiving the following error:
Warning: Undefined array key "password" in ...line 74
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHlOD.jpg

Line 74: if($_SESSION['password']=="123")

The login and submit button work fine and when logged-in the password-protected page displays properly without any error displayed.

How can I avoid the error on the initial login page?

```html
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit_pass']) && $_POST['pass'])
{
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 if($pass=="123")
 {
  $_SESSION['password']=$pass;
 }
 else
 {
  $error="Incorrect Password";
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['page_logout']))
{
 unset($_SESSION['password']);
}
?>

<?php if($_SESSION['password']=="123")
{
 ?>
                
        <h3>     Professional History.      </h3>
        
        <p> Photography. Business. Real Estate. Management. Accounts. Admin. Service.
        </p>
        
        <img src="img/side_panel.svg" alt="Place Holder"/>
            
        <form method="post" action="" id="logout_form">
            <input type="submit" name="page_logout" value="LOGOUT">
        </form>
 <?php
}
else
{
 ?>
        <form method="post" action="" id="login_form">
        <h1>LOGIN TO PROCEED</h1>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="*******">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_pass" value="SUBMIT">
        <p>"Password: 123"</p>
  
        </form>
 <?php  
}
?>
```

Comment: simply wrap your if($_SESSION['password']=="123") with an isset statement, since your password wont always be defined and throws the error... if you add

if(isset($_SESSION['password']) && $_SESSION['password']=="123")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not always have a password defined. If the value is 123, then you store it into `$_SESSION` as password, otherwise you create an error. This is only happening if you have a pass parameter. So:

- at initial loading before being signed in, no pass value is passed, hence the `if` is stepped over and then the password of `$_SESSION` is checked, which does not exist *yet*
- if the page is posted and you type something else than 123, then you will have the same error

Change this line

```
<?php if($_SESSION['password']=="123")
```

to this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['password']) && ($_SESSION['password']=="123"))
```

this will first check whether password exists in `$_SESSION` and will only refer to it if it does.